# Create MySQL database with python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to execute a file with parameters like this : ./file.py server adress arg2 arg3 arg4

**file1.py** :

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()

print "Database version : %s " % data

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: I'm really not sure about the question here. Is it the Python part you're asking for (then @john-zwinck gave already a good hint) or do you need a different HTML file every time?

Comment: You need to be more specifc about your environment and which part is calling what.
If you just want to run your script, use something like
`./file.py 127.0.0.1 arg2 arg3 arg4` and parse the parameters using argparse, as suggested by @john-zwinck

Comment: Again, you're supplying the wrong information - the operating system is not relevant here. Are you running something in a Python-based web framework, do you want to execute a Python script from the command line (then my previous commend gives the answer), and what is this HTML file all about?

Comment: execute the python script is not the problem, I execute already my script in command line with parameters, but the parameter server_adress I don't know how to get it. Because each user have a different server adress

Comment: Now where does this `sys.argv` come from, it is not mentioned anywhere in your example code. Also, `sys.argv` does not execute anything, as you can see in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), it gives you access to:
    _The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script._
(Taken literally from the docs.)

Comment: Besides that in your example above, the indentation is now completely off (which prevents it from being copy-pasted into Python), you **still** don't say how your Python script is being called. You leave it up to us to _guess_ if maybe `scriptHmtl.phtml` is the same as `file2.html` or whatever. Sorry, but I'm giving up now.

Comment: My question is clear, I have already passed as a parameter that I need to recover  and among them the address of the server. In file2.html I have that : action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py" , but it's not good because I must to make action=variable and in this variable recover the server adress of user .

Comment: Sorry but your question is _not_ clear. You still did not say which part is called by what, in which environment which part is running and how the names of your example files relate to those that you use _inside_ the examples (if so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in module [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).  Or `optparse` if you're stuck on Python 2.6 or earlier.

Comment: Method 1: read docs, write code.  Method 2: hire programmer.