# How do I recover the address server of user, put it in variable and execute it in command line

Tags: python, linux

**scriptInfo.py**

```
import os, sys, platform, webbrowser



def main()

  template = open('scriptHmtl.phtml').read()
```

**scriptHtml.phtml**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2><center> welcome </center></h2>
<br/><br/><br/>

...
variables
..

<form name="sendData" method="get" action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py">
    Name: <input type="text" name="n"><br/><br/>
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fn"/><br/><br/>
    Mail: <input type="text" name="ma"/><br/><br/>
    Address: <input type="text" name="add"/> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
```

Instead of `action="http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py"`, there must be a variable which contain the code to recover the server address, but I don't want how to do it.

Comment: You are writing a form, which implies that you yourself are running a server. So I'm not sure what good you expect an IP address from the other end to do you. How do you even know that the user is running a server?

Comment: Or do you mean that the USER runs this code? If so, why can't they just run their server on 127.0.0.1 and access it locally?

Comment: no the have only access to the page, when it executes ./scriptInfo.py localhost:8000 .. param2 param3 param4, the webbrower opens a page with some data etc...

Comment: It is the same question as they posted yesterday under a different topic (and username btw), where all this information you (@holdenweb) are asking for is missing as well. I was trying to ask for those missing pieces, but eventually gave up.
At least this time the relation between the files is a bit more clear, in the initial posting they were not even replying to my question(s) regarding this point.
Here's the original post (edited and fully changed by now): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610611/get-a-server-adress-as-a-parameters-to-exceute-in-command-line#comment38173332_24610611

Comment: In the meantime the edit of the other question has been reverted, so now it is in fact a full duplicate again.

Comment: yes that approximately the same thing, but I want to put in a variable how to recover any server address when executed by command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTML forms you can just ignore the server and go straight to the script.

For example like

```
<form name="sendData" method="get" action="cgi/scriptGet.py">
```

Comment: yes I know that, but I must not to call a file or an URL, but a variable to recover the server address, you know ?

Comment: You mean (in this case) you'd want the IP address associated with `localhost`? Please clarify.

Comment: Do you already understand that "localhost" (127.0.0.1) always means "the same machine this code is running on"?

Comment: of course I know that, but IP of user is not the same of me .